# Fatal Error grpc-android-1.50.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. When intergrating Firebase and Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have been away from Flutter and Firebase developing for a while now. I have come back to complete a project and did what I always used to do when connecting the two but now it does even compile. I followed the official docs and as far as I can tell it worked the way it was meant too .

Here is the error I get:

```
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.50.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore > com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.2
      > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.50.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.50.2/grpc-stub-1.50.2.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

and here is my app build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

please let me know if I need to add anything else. I have tried googling but came up with nothing as I have no idea what to search or what I change. The app does run without all the firebase things

Thanks for any help!

Edit to add Pubspec:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: @tomerpacific Okay will add it to the post thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using previous versions of cloud firestore?